# shuf command to extract lines with spaces in CSV file

Tags: bash, shuffle

I have a CSV file with set of 1000 addresses. I used shuf command to shuffle the 10 lines randomly for a process. Since the addresses are available with spaces, the shuf command collects all 10 addresses into a single element in an array rather than 10 different elements in the array. Please help resolving the issue.

**Sample CSV**

```
from_address
"303 Co Rd 405, Floresville, TX 78114,US"
"4422 Oakside Dr, Houston, TX 77053,US"
"4218 S 245th Ct, Kent, WA 98032,US"
"1407 Marion Manor Dr, Marion, VA 24354,US"
"7400 Englewood Ave, Yakima, WA 98908,US"
"8012 Burly Wood Way, Hampton, GA 30253,US"
"931 Beacon Square Ct, Gaithersburg, MD 20878,US"
"12 Truval la, Nesconset, NY 11767,US"
"121 Pet Rock Ct, Clayton, NC 27520,US"
"235 Whitaker Rd, Westfield, PA 16950,US"
"13422 NE 133rd St, Kirkland, WA 98034,US"
"1620 27th St NW, Canton, OH 44709,US"
"488 Andrews Rd, Columbus, GA 31903,US"
"4742 Janet Ln, Bethlehem, PA 18017,US"
"2622 Cherokee Ct, West Palm Beach, FL 33406,US"
"111 Westbury Ct, Doylestown, PA 18901,US"
"820 Main St, Belpre, OH 45714,US"
"1307 Stevenson Ln, Towson, MD 21286,US"
"2725 Hartford Rd, East York, PA 17402,US"
"9 Winding Brook Rd, Rhinebeck, NY 12572,US"
"433 Willowbrook Dr, Norristown, PA 19403,US"
"208 N Kayla Dr, Granite Quarry, NC 28146,US"
"931 Pimlico Dr, Centerville, OH 45459,US"
```

**Shell Script**

```
list_=("$(shuf -n 10 sample_addresses.csv)")
echo ${#list_[@]}
```

**Expected Result**

10

**Actual Result**

1

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) -- `array=( $(anything) )` is bad practice in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
list_=("$(shuf -n 10 sample_addresses.csv)")
```

That's creating a list with one single element.

To read the *lines* into an array, use the [`mapfile` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile):

```sh
mapfile -t list_ < <(shuf -n 10 sample_addresses.csv)
```

A good way to inspect the contents of a variable is

```sh
declare -p list_
```